# Django ORM underscore wildcard

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have been searching for a way of using Django ORM to use the SQL underscore wildcard, and do something equivalent to this:

```html
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field LIKE 'abc_wxyz'
```

Currently, I am doing:

```html
field_like = 'abc_wxyz'
result = MyClass.objects.extra(where=["field LIKE " + field_like])
```

I already tried with contains() and icontains(), but that's not what I need, since what it does is adding parenthesis to the query:

```html
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field LIKE '%abc/_wxyz%'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by adding paranthesis to the query? In general, on Django ORM, contains is equivalent to '%abc%', startswith is equivalent to 'abc%' and endswith is equivalent to '%abc'

Comment: You're right, I meant percentage character

Comment: I didn't notice the "_" character in your query. You can use "__regex " to use a regular expression for filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **__regex** lookup to build more complex lookup expressions than **__contains**, **__startswith** or **__endswith** (can add "i" character to beginning of each of these to make lookups case insensitive, like icontains). In your case, I think

```
MyClass.objects.filter(field__regex=r'^abc.wxyz$')
```

Would do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `field__contains` [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains).

for example:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(field__contains='abc_wxyz')
```

This is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE field LIKE 'abc_wxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lord Elron's answer is incorrect. Django escapes all developer supplied wildcard characters to the LIKE-type lookups. The statement is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE field LIKE '%abc/_wxyz%'
```

(as the OP discovered) and the underscore has no effect.

See [Escaping percent signs and underscores in LIKE statements](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements)

> The field lookups that equate to LIKE SQL statements (iexact, contains, icontains, startswith, istartswith, endswith and iendswith) will automatically escape the two special characters used in LIKE statements – the percent sign and the underscore.